# Sending page URL with Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am looking to dynamically submit the page URL of which a user submits a contact form from.

So for example if someone used a contact form on the home page the URL (https://www.example.com/) would be added to the email, and this would change depending on which page the user submitted the page from.

Now then, I have tried using -

```
 $absolute_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Yes this does work, however, the URL I get through is as follows:

**From URL:**

http://example.com/email/index.php

This, I imagine, is because the mailer script is in its own directory and separate file, which is where $absolute_url is fetching from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Cal.

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: js `window.location.href`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. Managed to get it working with $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need current URL value. @Pupil's function can do the trick but you might have one problem.

Not every server set $_SERVER['HTTPS'] so you can get an error that says that HTTPS is not in $_SERVER array. Something like:

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in..

It's because you can't do compare if key doesn't exist.

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
```

You should use `isset()` because it checks whether a variable is "set" or available for reference. So you better go with:

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] )) {$pageURL .= "s";}
```

You can even suppress the possible notice using the "@" operator but you should then change function logic a bit. You could have then:

```
  function getCurrentUrl(){
      $pageURL  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] : 'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
      $pageURL .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      return $pageURL;
        }    
echo getCurrentUrl();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Great explanation, all is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You Could create a hidden input in the form that contains URL.

HTML in form

```
<input id="ref" name="url" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("ref").setAttribute("value",window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems, you want current page url.

Here is the function for the same:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
echo curPageURL();
?>
```

Comment: This could return error notice if HTTPS is not in $_SERVER array.